# Tracking changes in lines or paragraphs between text file revisions

Tags: python, algorithm, version-control, wiki

I'm investigating building an inline commenting system over a wiki (but this is *not* the question). The first thing that comes to mind is being able to associate a comment to a line, paragraph or string with a unique ID. Then to have this association remain valid over multiple edits of the wiki.

For example, from this input:

R1:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 
4 Three
5 Four
```

R2:

```
1 One
2 Three
3 Two
4
5 Four
```

I'd like to have a mapping between lines 1⇒1, 2⇒3, 3⇒4, 5⇒5 and know a new line 2 was added and 4 was removed. Dealing with line 4 moving to line 2 is probably starting to make some wild guesses, I'm not sure.

There are lots of tools that do similar text operations (no, I'm *not* after a tool). Diff, version control and revision merging come to mind. **Are there well known *algorithms* to track content between file changes?** My preference is for python but am interested to know about others too.

Comment: OK, I have to ask. Do I smell? I thought this was a pretty concise (not too broad) question about programming that hasn't been covered before (not with a similar title at least). Why the close voting?

Comment: Probably because you could have found the kind of information you're looking for by Googling `diff` or `text merge algorithms`.

Comment: @kindall ok. now thanks to me, you can also google for tracking changes too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have heard of `diff`, you are probably interested in the [Hunt-McIlroy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93McIlroy_algorithm) on which (and other tools of its type) it is based. By the way, `diff` is available in Python as `difflib`.

Actual revision tracking (like Word does when "Track Changes" is on) requires tagging the text in some way and can't really be done with plain text. But diff and merge algorithms are pretty damn good at figuring this out.